# Running Sagemaker Studio Notebook using Papermill

Tags: amazon-sagemaker-studio, papermill

I'm trying to run sagemaker studio notebooks from within another sagemaker studio notebook using papermill. When I try to do this I get a "NoSuchKernel" Error. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5i1u.png). Any ideas on how to resolve or other options for solving the same problem (unfortunately I get a connection error when I try to install safemaker-run-notebook).

Thanks!